# Best approach bzr on deploy server

Tags: svn, bazaar

I have online web applications running at VPS.

I want to add BZR or SVN, now some questions:

- Currently i run BZR over SSH, which requires some manual actions over terminal.
  Would a SVN-server power up my remote possibilites w/o need for ssh login?
- The roles-management is a mess and I can't find a way out of it.
  Webserver running as www-user and BZR-merge is done with another user-account.
  As a result - I need to su root for any commit and chown files back to www-user.
- Currently I'm the only developer on the project, but others may join. Should i
  run the webserver as a regular user? (groups are of course set up; www-user part of remote-user and remote-user part of www-user - but still a mess.)

If any of you can supply a brilliant, fix-and-forget solution I'd be ever so greatful.

regards,
//t

Comment: There shouldn't be any manual actions required over terminal, what do you have to do?

Comment: I just modified webserver to run as login user instead of www-data. Seems pretty sleek. Is it the best bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "manual actions" you mean typing your password, you can use an ssh-agent to overcome that. Generate an SSH key, add it to the authorized_keys for your user on the server and then add it to your local ssh-agent. Bazaar should not have to prompt you for your password once this is done.

Bazaar over SSH is the best way to do it since it allows Bazaar to run on the server and provide "smart" protocol access. Bazaar over "dumb" protocols like HTTP will be slower.